# Fetch all time date_histogram buckets results

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-query

I have the below query to fetch aggregations using Elasticsearch 7.1.

```
{ 
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "filter": [ 
        { 
          "bool": { 
            "must": [ 
              { 
                "match": { 
                  "viewedInFeed": true
                } 
              }
            ] 
          } 
        } 
      ] 
    } 
  },
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": { 
    "viewed_in_feed_by_day": { 
      "date_histogram": { 
        "field": "createdDate", 
        "interval" : "day",
        "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd",
        "min_doc_count": 1
      } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

The results are greater than 10,000 and I am not sure how to work since `scroll` is not available for aggregations. See the response below.

```
{
    "took": 3,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 10000,
            "relation": "gte"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "viewed_in_feed_by_day": {
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key_as_string": "2020-03-19",
                    "key": 1584576000000,
                    "doc_count": 3028
                },
                {
                    "key_as_string": "2020-03-20",
                    "key": 1584662400000,
                    "doc_count": 5384
                },
                {
                    "key_as_string": "2020-03-21",
                    "key": 1584748800000,
                    "doc_count": 3521
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

When using `_count` the count of documents is greater than 10,000 and even without the `"min_doc_count": 1` doesn't return results, I know there are more data anyway.

Comment: "date_histogram" groups data on given intervals. A bucket from your result                     {"key_as_string": "2020-03-19",  "key": 1584576000000,  "doc_count": 3028  } if you will look at doc count it shows that 3028 documents have date as "2020-03-19" so is it possible that returned documents have just 3 dates

Comment: OK! I didn't notice the count of documents are actually sum greater to 10,000. Kind of confusing. So, I actually can ignore the 'hits' values.

Comment: In hits relation is gte. So hits are greater than 10000. To get actual count you can use value_count aggregation. I didn't get the confusion, you have from your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on top of Jaspreet's comments I suggest the following:

- Use `track_total_hits=true` to get the exact counts (since [7.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-7.0.html#track-total-hits-10000-default)) while keeping the `size=0` to only aggregate.
- Use the `stats` aggregation to gain more insights before running your histograms.

```
GET dates/_search
{ 
  "track_total_hits": true,               
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": { 
    "dates_insights": {
      "stats": {
        "field": "createdDate"
      }
    },
    "viewed_in_feed_by_day": { 
      "date_histogram": { 
        "field": "createdDate", 
        "interval" : "month",
        "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd",
        "min_doc_count": 1
      } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

yielding

```
...
"hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 3,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "viewed_in_feed_by_day" : {
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2020-01-01",
          "key" : 1577836800000,
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2020-02-01",
          "key" : 1580515200000,
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2020-03-01",
          "key" : 1583020800000,
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    },
    "dates_insights" : {
      "count" : 3,
      ...
      "min_as_string" : "2020-01-22T13:09:21.588Z",
      "max_as_string" : "2020-03-22T13:09:21.588Z",
      ...
    }
  }
...
```

Comment: is it possible to distinct the 'doc_count' in buckets results by specific document field?

Comment: You're welcome. Not sure what you mean with "doc count by spec. doc field"... What should the end response look like?

Comment: I actually found it by using a Cardinality aggregate in "viewed_in_feed_by_day" aggregate